# YouTube API v3 - Request upload permission - Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, android-youtube-api

I am currently uploading a video to YouTube using the YouTube API v3 for Android based on the code [**here**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video):

I want to perform the upload after a delay, when the user may no longer be in the app. The problem I am coming across is that if the user has not already granted permissions for my app to upload to YouTube, it will raise a `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` on upload. The documentation then suggests I should do:

```
startActivityForResult(uraioe.getIntent(), ACTION_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
```

which displays a pop up. At this point, if the user has left the app, it is a bad experience for them to see the pop up, if they see it at all. Can I pre-authorize my app to have upload permission, before I upload a file?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [access and refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps). While your user is using the app, they can authenticate their account and allow you to make requests on their behalf, resulting in the creation of an access token and refresh token. Then if they go offline, you just need to check if the access token has expired (generally an hour after creation) and if it has, use the refresh token and you can make authorized requests for them.

Note that tokens can [expire](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) if:

> - the user has revoked access.
> - The token has not been used for six months.
> - The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests.